# Convolution theorem if one function depends on the reciprocal space in a non-trivial way

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, fourier-analysis, convolution

I would like to write the following integral in terms of a convolution:

\begin{equation}
H(x_1,x_2) = \int dt e^{\mathrm{i} t (x_1+x_2)/2} f(t,x_1,x_2) g(t),
\end{equation}
where $f(t,x_1,x_2)$ depends also on $x_1$ and $x_2$ in a non-trivial way.
However, I happen to know the solutions to these integrals:

\begin{equation}
F(x_1,x_2) = \int dt  e^{\mathrm{i} t (x_1+x_2)/2} f(t,x_1,x_2)
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
G(x_1,x_2) = \int dt  e^{\mathrm{i} t (x_1+x_2)/2} g(t).
\end{equation}

I would like to write the first integral as a convolution using the convolution theorem:

\begin{equation}
H(x_1,x_2) = F(x_1,x_2) \ast G(x_1,x_2),
\end{equation}

1. Is this possible?
2. If yes, how would I write this convolution in integral form?

As a note: $G(x_1,x_2)= G(x_1 + x_2)$ only depends on the sum of $x_1$ and $x_2$, however,
$F(x_1,x_2)$ does not.

Comment: These Fourier-like integrals are from -infinity to infinity?

Comment: The information that you have is not enough. Besides $F(x_1,x_2) = \int dt  e^{\mathrm{i} t (x_1+x_2)/2} f(t,x_1,x_2)$ you need something like $\int dt  e^{\mathrm{i} t [(x_1+x_2)/2 - y]} f(t,x_1,x_2)$. Can you compute such an integral?

Comment: @Daniel Lichtblau yes they are from -infinity to infinity!

Comment: @yarchik,  yes I can compute such an integral

Comment: Ok, I will write a solution soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us introduce:
$$
\tilde{G}(y) = \int dt  e^{\mathrm{i} t y} g(t),\\
g(t') = \int \frac{dy}{2\pi}  e^{-\mathrm{i} t' y} \tilde{G}(y). 
$$
and substitute in the original equation
$$
H(x_1,x_2) = \int dt e^{\mathrm{i} t (x_1+x_2)/2} f(t,x_1,x_2) g(t)\\
 =\int dt \int \frac{dy}{2\pi} e^{\mathrm{i}t [(x_1+x_2)/2- y]} f(t,x_1,x_2) \tilde{G}(y).
$$
Now exchange the integration order
$$
H(x_1,x_2)
 =\int \frac{dy}{2\pi}  \tilde{G}(y) \int dt  e^{\mathrm{i}t [(x_1+x_2)/2- y]} f(t,x_1,x_2)
$$
and introduce
$$
\tilde{F}(y; x_1,x_2)=\int dt  e^{\mathrm{i}t [(x_1+x_2)/2- y]} f(t,x_1,x_2).
$$
In the comment it is written that the last integral can be computed. Therefore
$$
H(x_1,x_2)
 =\int \frac{dy}{2\pi}  \tilde{G}(y) \tilde{F}(y; x_1,x_2).
$$

If $f(t, x_1, x_2)$ depends only on the sum $x_1+x_2$ the latter expression reduces to a convolution.